# AWS CloudFront for multiple subdomain

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have CloudFront for `example.com` & `www.example.com` with `*.example.com` wildcard certificate. But now I want to add `w.example.com`, `ww.example.com` & `wwww.example.com` so i have added these new subdomains to CF configuration [ Alternate domain names ].
CF is pointed to Apache Web Server for dynamic contents and to S3 for static contents.

`nslookup` can resolved newly added domain to cloudfront DNS. But it doesn't work in browser when I try to open `w.domain.com` Error is `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.  What I am missing here ?

Comment: What exactly does "It doesn't work in browser" mean?